# Is there a way to force install4j auto updater to update the current version?

Tags: auto-update, install4j

I've been iterating versions of my application trough beta and install4j auto-updater was updating successfully trough versions (2.1 -> 3.0b0 -> 3.0b1 -> 3.0b2). Now I've published version 3.0 and auto-updater is refusing to recognize the new version.
Now, I know that there is an option that allows you to customize update scheme but it's too late now since I didn't know that when I was publishing older versions.
I've played around with it and it updates to 4.0 and 3.0b3 but fails to recognize 3.0, 3.1.

So, is there a way to force auto updater to update by manipulating the new update.xml file?

EDIT: I have version 4.2.8 of install4j installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. install4j 5 will correctly update from  3.0b2 to 3.0, but in install4j 4 you would have to modify the updater logic, so you would first have to release a 3.0b4 to do that.